# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Error 'Unable to cast object of type' while Scaffolding Existing Database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.0

I am using Visual Studio  2019. My application is in ASP.NET Core 3.0.

I'm trying to scaffold an existing database from LocalDb using the Package Manager Console with this command:

```
 Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;
 Database=hamdoonsoft;Trusted_Connection=True;" 
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Appcontext
```

After a while I'm getting this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.RelationalLoggingDefinitions' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Diagnostics.Internal.SqlServerLoggingDefinitions'.

What's causing it and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I suspect you updated Visual Studio.  There is a mapping file between the c# application and the database that is inconsistent.  Entity creates a set of classes that are used as part of the mapping.  When the database changes or versions of SQL Server or Net the mapping also need to be updated.

Comment: For installing some tools from "Tools> Get tools and Features" I updated the "Visual Studio installer" by Force. Now what will be the solution?

Comment: Why do something in code when it is only needed to be done every 5 years?  What is wrong with doing it manually when needed?

Comment: Are you telling about code first?

Comment: If the update of the database takes 30 seconds to run do you want to do the check every time you application starts?

Comment: Oh! Now Please , what would be the solution?

Comment: Is it working now?  Only synchronize the app with the database when versions change.

Comment: It is working well in .net core 2.1 with out any problem but not in 3.0

Comment: The mapping is different between 2.1 and 3.0 and need to be updated for 3.0.

Comment: Sorry for late contact. I was in EID vacation. Which portion need to be updated?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue in [EFCore Preview 4](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15414), which was targeted to be fixed in Preview 5. Having encountered this issue myself, I can confirm that updating to Preview 5, which leaves my .csproj references for EFCore looking like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview5.19227.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview5.19227.1" />
```

Has resolved the issue and allowed me to scaffold a DBContext.

Comment: What thing I have to do now; copying this code and replacing the existing one in .csproj?

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman, you need to update your package references for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*`, by editing your project file, using the Package Manager Console or the NuGet Package Manager - how you do it is up to you =)

Comment: I have default this two

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19216.3" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview4.19216.3" />

Comment: How to update to updating to Preview 5? Is it possible by nuget? Nuget is saying latest versions of different library of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.* is 2.something.

Comment: That's because you've not told it to use pre-release packages, see here for more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/prerelease-packages#installing-and-updating-pre-release-packages

Comment: While installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Version="3.0.0-preview5.19227.1" getting 3 errors first one is Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for

Comment: That's (a) a different question, and (b) not enough information to go on to stand a chance of answering it, I'm afraid